# C# Webrequest json to object

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization, javascriptserializer

I'm trying to convert this JSON to an object of a class but I get the error: ":" or "{" expected.

This is the JSON:

```
{"data":[{"id":"https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.0", 
"name": "Epic Games' Fortnite",
"url": "https:\/\/www.epicgames.com\/fortnite\/", 
"about": [{"name": "Fortnite"}]]}
```

Here are the classes:

```
class WebResult
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string[] about { get; set; }
}

class Results
{
    public List<WebResult> data { get; set; }
}
```

Here comes the error:

```
Results result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Results>(json);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is invalid. It should be:

```
var json = {"data":[{"id":"https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.0", 
"name": "Epic Games' Fortnite",
"url": "https:\/\/www.epicgames.com\/fortnite\/", 
"about": [{"name": "Fortnite"}]}]}
```

Also your class should have an About class:

```
public class Results
{
    public List<WebResult> Data { get; set; }
}
public class WebResult
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public List<About> About { get; set; }
}
public class About
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To deserialize, you can do the following:

```
var deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = deserializer.Deserialize<Results>(json);
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

You have to close first object in `data` table. As said in error message, closing `}` is missing after closing `about` table.

```
{
    "data":
    [
        {
            "id":"https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/#WebPages.0",
            "name":"Epic Games' Fortnite",
            "url":"https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/",
            "about":[ { "name":"Fortnite" } ]
        }  <-- missing
    ]
}
```

You can use an online json parser ([like this one](http://json.parser.online.fr/)) to quickly resolve syntax errors.

Your C# models seems to be invalid for this json. For creating C# classes out of json check out [quicktype](https://quicktype.io/?l=cs).